# C# how to call “sp_executesql” for bulk insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, load, sp-executesql

I have files whic needs to be loaded to db  with win form application 
for that  i am creationg  bulkload string  C# code

```
  private void bt_loadInToTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bulkinsert = " BULK INSERT " + tableName + " FROM " + filePath +
        " WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',BATCHSIZE = 1000,  CHECK_CONSTRAINTS = ON , ERRORFILE = '" + tableName + "file_name.txt' )";

            using (SqlConnection thisConnectionT = new SqlConnection("Server=" + serverName + ";User Id=" + uName + ";Password=" + pass + ";Database=" + dbName + ";"))
            {

                thisConnectionT.Open();

                new SqlCommand(bulkinsert, thisConnectionT);
               // bulkinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
```

however I guess i am calling it some how wrong, because its not loading, but  not  trowing  an error
call supposed to be as `exec sp_executesql bulkinsert`.

this  C# code should replace  this **SQL** code which  is  running

```
DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(2000)
set @bulkinsert = 'BULK INSERT ForTest FROM ''D:\\forBulk\\fortest.csv'' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',BATCHSIZE = 1000 )'

EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert
```

If I am running it from  sql side its insert records but From C# not

Sorry its may be a dumb question but I am DB developer

Comment: Print the bulkinsert string in C#, copy into your SQL editor and attempt to run. Any issues?

Comment: @nbot yes ts working , but  from application doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using the `SqlBulkCopy` class as explained in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhilsi/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app/).

As a quick aside, I'd avoid building queries via string concatenation to mitigate against sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The following sends the query EXEC('SELECT 1') to your connection.

```
new SqlCommand("EXEC('SELECT 1')", connection);
```

Comment: but  i need to send this  "BULK INSERT " + tableName + " FROM " + filePath +
        " WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',BATCHSIZE = 1000,  CHECK_CONSTRAINTS = ON  )";

Comment: The OP is asking how to do bulk copy from C# and now how to send a command through.

Comment: C# is not responsible for reading the file and inserting into DB. C# should be kicking off a bulk insert with a string query, and then SQL should be reading the file...

Comment: @nbot than is what  i am trying to achieve, I am building string  with sql bulk statement and I need to send it to the sql server